# How to make custom_header_setup() image as background image?

Tags: headers, custom-header

I have created a function that enables Header Image in Wordpress (5.0.3) ACP. My HTML code treats that image as normal image (not background).

```
<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

How can I make my custom header as background image?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have used it as an image.
`<img src="//..." height="..." width="..."/>`

This code is used to display images, not background images.

Use it with text:

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">Example of a DIV element with a background image:</div>
```

Or without text:

```
<div style="background-image: url(../images/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"> </div>
```

Source is [enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0301/0301-CSS-DIV-BACKGROUND-IMAGE.html)

I tried it with the header tag...

```
<header style="background-image: url(.../images.png)";>
Your text here.
</header>
```